# VB.NET: DataGridView ColumnHeader Text Indent Value

Tags: vb.net, text, datagridview, header, datagridviewcolumn

Is it possible to get the `DataGridViewColumn` Header Text-margin (text-indent) value in VB.NET? I need this to calculate the correct text width with the `TextRenderer`. Because column width is always larger than the allowed space for column header text. I just want to know its' exact value.

Thanks!

P.S. Column width - TextRenderer([text], [font]).Width is not wat I ask.
I explain why: before setting a text value as column header text, I check if my text is not larger than the allowed text space (which I don't have) of header cell. If it is larger, my text is edited to make it shorter and points are added at the end. My text, together with those points has then the correct width to be set to the column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found:
`[MyDataGridViewColumn].HeaderCell.ContentBounds.Left`